# Trigger is not working

Tags: apex, trigger

in rollup trigger when i delete last record in child object(Budget_Allocation__c) & field(budget__c) its parent object field (Budget_Allocation_Total__c) not update.
like if two record of child  1 budget value = 80 and  2 is also 120 so total is Budget_Allocation_Total__c = 200. when i deleted 1 record parent field become 120,and 2 record deleted its also 120.so how i can set this field blank in trigger.?

```
trigger budgetallocation on Budget_Allocation__c(after insert,after update,after delete) {
    set<id> oppid = new set<id>();
      if(trigger.isupdate || trigger.isinsert){
        for(Budget_Allocation__c ba :trigger.new){
            if(ba.Opportunity1__c!=null && ba.Budget__c!=null){
                oppid.add(ba.Opportunity1__c);
                system.debug('--oppp-->'+oppid);
            }
        }
      }  
     AggregateResult[] Result = [select Opportunity1__c, Sum(Budget__c) from Budget_Allocation__c where Opportunity1__c IN: oppid group by Opportunity1__c]; 
    System.debug('Result====='+Result);
    List<Opportunity__c> Opplist = New list<Opportunity__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ar: Result){

            Opportunity__c opp = new Opportunity__c();
            opp.Id=(Id)ar.get('Opportunity1__c');
            opp.Budget_Allocation_Total__c=(decimal)ar.get('expr0');        
            Opplist.add(opp);
        }
             if(Opplist!=null && Opplist.size()>0){  
                update Opplist; 
             } 

             /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*--------------------------Proposal Rollup--------------------------------------*/   
    set<id> ppid = new set<id>();
      if(trigger.isupdate || trigger.isinsert){
        for(Budget_Allocation__c ba :trigger.new){
            if(ba.Proposal__c!=null && ba.Budget__c!=null){
                ppid.add(ba.Proposal__c);

            }    
         }

       }
       if(trigger.isdelete){

               for(Budget_Allocation__c ba:trigger.old){

                        ppid.add(ba.Proposal__c);

               }
           }  

        List<Proposal__c> pplist = New list<Proposal__c>();
        AggregateResult[] Result1 = [select Proposal__c, Sum(Budget__c) from Budget_Allocation__c where Proposal__c IN: ppid group by Proposal__c]; 

         for(AggregateResult ar: Result1){
          Proposal__c pp = new Proposal__c();
             pp.Id=(Id)ar.get('Proposal__c');
             pp.Budget_Allocation_Total__c=(decimal)ar.get('expr0');
             pplist.add(pp);
         }
          if(pplist!=null && pplist .size()>0){
           update pplist ; 

        }
}
```

Comment: instead of Aggregate query use inner query. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Aggregate query` use `inner query`. That will solve your problem.

because when you delete all child so you will not get any record for that parent in your aggregate query so it will not clear the value. So make query on parent and based on child total update the value.